# How can I make this jQuery animation appear on the actual div that it's clicked on?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, multiple-instances

Hello I am currently working on this animation of a pair of scissors cutting out a coupon... It works great if there is a [single coupon on the page](http://extremecouponnetwork.com/children-toys.html) but with multiple coupons it slows WAY down and acts sporadically?

[Multiple Example](http://extremecouponnetwork.com/coupon-categories.html)

I am trying to make it so that when you click "CLIP IT!" at the bottom of a coupon... The animation appears on THAT coupon and only that coupon!

UPDATE: I have made it a little further but am still unable to get the animation working on the site as it is slightly different than the awesome examples that were provided... Basically I have multiple divs with a class of .item and the examples have only 1...

THANKS FOR HELPING... I've learned a bit!

Here is the code from my .js file:

```
    jQuery(function($){

    //try this
    $(window).load(function(){



    });

    $(".clip_it").click(clipIt);

    function clipIt(){

            $(".ToBeAnimated").fadeIn();
            animationLoop();
            // jfbc.opengraph.triggerAction('1','http://www.extremecouponnetwork.com<?php echo $this->item->link; ?>');
    }

    function animationLoop() {

        $(".ToBeAnimated").css({
            top: ($(".item .item-inner").offset().top - parseInt($(".ToBeAnimated").height()) / 2),
            left: ($(".item .item-inner").offset().left - parseInt($(".ToBeAnimated").width()) / 2)
        }).rotate(270);

        $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
            top: $(".item .item-inner").offset().top + $(".item .item-inner").height() - $(".ToBeAnimated").height() / 2
        }, 1000, function() {
            $(this).animate({
                rotate: "180deg"
            },1000, function() {
                $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
                    left: $(".item .item-inner").offset().left + $(".item .item-inner").width() - $(".ToBeAnimated").width() / 2
                }, 1000, function() {
                    $(this).animate({
                        rotate: "90deg"
                    }, function() {
                        $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
                            top: $(".item .item-inner").offset().top - $(".ToBeAnimated").height() / 2
                        }, 1000, function() {
                            $(this).animate({
                                rotate: "0deg"
                            }, function() {
                                $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
                                    left: $(".ToBeAnimated").width() / 2
                                }, 1000, function() {
                                    setTimeout(animationLoop, 1000);
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });

                });
            });
        });
    }     
});
```

Comment: Could you make a gif and display it over top of a static sisccor image when the button is clicked and hide it after the period it takes the gif to end?

Comment: my eyes are tired from walking up and down your code staircase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(".clip_it").on("click", function () {
    animationLoop($(this).closest(".item-inner").eq(0),$(this).parent().find(".ToBeAnimated").eq(0));
  });
});
  function animationLoop(ctx,ctx2) {
    ctx2.fadeIn();
    ctx2.css({
      top: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.height()) / 2),
      left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2),
      position:"absolute",
      "z-index":800
    }).rotate(270);
    ctx2.animate({
      top: ctx.height() - ctx2.height() / 2
    }, 1000, function () {
      ctx2.animate({
        rotate: "180deg"
      }, 1000, function () {
        ctx2.animate({
          left: ctx.width() - ctx2.width() / 2
        }, 1000, function () {
          ctx2.animate({
            rotate: "90deg"
          }, function () {
            ctx2.animate({
              top: 0-ctx2.height() / 2
            }, 1000, function () {
              ctx2.animate({
                rotate: "0deg"
              }, function () {
                ctx2.animate({
                  left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2)
                }, 1000, function () {
                  setTimeout(animationLoop(ctx,ctx2), 1000);
                });
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

What it does, is that it doesn't rely on offsetTop or offsetLeft, since setting the scissors to absolute [not fixed], will animate it relatively to it's containing parent [the coupon itself; `.item-inner`]. So, a position of "0" is enough to put any scissors to the top left hand corner of the coupon.

The click pass to function trick is used, to retain the clicked and animated scissors into memory, so that one instance of the animation for each of the scissors occurs without a hitch. Also, with that, the objects of each scissors is already stored/selected for each instance, and is unneeded [meaning that there is no need to reference `$(".ToBeAnimated")`)]

*[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bFkju/24/show/) **|** [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/bFkju/24/)*

**Edit:**

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$("body").on("click", ".clip_it", function () {
if ($(this).parent().find(".clip_it").length<1){
$(this).after('<a class="clip_it" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="">CLIP IT!</a><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v29/wormholes201/animated-scissors.gif" class="ToBeAnimated">');
}
    animationLoop($(this).closest(".item-inner").eq(0),$(this).parent().find(".ToBeAnimated").eq(0));
  });
});
  function animationLoop(ctx,ctx2) {
    ctx2.fadeIn();
    ctx2.css({
      top: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.height()) / 2),
      left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2),
      position:"absolute",
      "z-index":800
    }).rotate(270);
    ctx2.animate({
      top: ctx.height() - ctx2.height() / 2
    }, 1000, function () {
      ctx2.animate({
        rotate: "180deg"
      }, 1000, function () {
        ctx2.animate({
          left: ctx.width() - ctx2.width() / 2
        }, 1000, function () {
          ctx2.animate({
            rotate: "90deg"
          }, function () {
            ctx2.animate({
              top: 0-ctx2.height() / 2
            }, 1000, function () {
              ctx2.animate({
                rotate: "0deg"
              }, function () {
                ctx2.animate({
                  left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2)
                }, 1000, function () {
                  setTimeout(animationLoop(ctx,ctx2), 1000);
                });
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

**Edit2:**
There seems to be [additional codes](http://extremecouponnetwork.com/templates/ja_wall/js/clip.js) not functioning properly in your [multidemo page](http://extremecouponnetwork.com/coupon-categories.html):

Here's a fix:

```
/* Begin */
jQuery(function ($) {

    reloadMasonry = function () {
        $(document.body).addClass('masonry-relayout');
        $container.masonry('reload', function () {
            $(document.body).removeClass('masonry-relayout');
        });
    };


    /* When any "click_it" link is clicked in the body, method used since .live() is deprecated and removed in jQuery 1.9 */
    $("body").on("click", ".clip_it", function () {

        /* Checks to see if there is a scissors and adds one if there's not */
        if ($(this).parent().find(".clip_it").length < 1) {
            $(this).after('<a class="clip_it" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="">CLIP IT!</a><img src="http://img.photobucket.com/albums/v29/wormholes201/animated-scissors.gif" class="ToBeAnimated">');
        }

        /* Starts the animation */
        animationLoop($(this).closest(".item-inner").eq(0), $(this).parent().find(".ToBeAnimated").eq(0));
    });

    /* Function that starts the animation queue, "ctx" is the container while "ctx2" is the sissors */
    function animationLoop(ctx, ctx2) {
        ctx2.fadeIn();
        ctx2.css({
            top: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.height()) / 2),
            left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2),
            position: "absolute",
                "z-index": 800
        }).rotate(270);
        ctx2.animate({
            top: ctx.height() - ctx2.height() / 2
        }, 1000, function () {
            ctx2.animate({
                rotate: "180deg"
            }, 1000, function () {
                ctx2.animate({
                    left: ctx.width() - ctx2.width() / 2
                }, 1000, function () {
                    ctx2.animate({
                        rotate: "90deg"
                    }, function () {
                        ctx2.animate({
                            top: 0 - ctx2.height() / 2
                        }, 1000, function () {
                            ctx2.animate({
                                rotate: "0deg"
                            }, function () {
                                ctx2.animate({
                                    left: (0 - parseInt(ctx2.width()) / 2)
                                }, 1000, function () {
                                    /* Event queue is completed! The sissors should be back at it's default position */
                                    $container = $('#masonry-container');

                                    /* "$(this)" is actually "ctx" here */
                                    var jremove = ctx.closest('.item').hide();
                                    $container.masonry('remove', jremove);
                                    reloadMasonry();
                                    return false;
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Wowzer... That is fantastic... Thank you VERY MUCH... I do have one question however?  All the new items that are appended with infinite scroll don't work with the animation? I am not sure why?

Comment: Indeed the edited script works very well! :) 

I am however, trying to figure out why "infinite scroll" items don't support the animation... When you click on any of the newly appended coupons nothing happens... No errors either... Trying to solve now?!

THANKS AGAIN... REALLY <3

Answer (score 4):

You should animate the specific element that's been clicked. By specific I mean you only animate the scissors where the 'clip it' button is clicked. `$(".ToBeAnimated")` would select all scissors, regardless weather they are clicked. So instead, you'd rewrite the click handler like the following:

```
function clipIt(){
    var $scissor = $(this).closest('.ToBeAnimated');
        $scissor.fadeIn();
        animationLoop($scissor);
}

function animationLoop($elem) {
    // only animate the intended scissors, not all of them
    $elem.css(...); // your animation code..
}
```

Likewise, in your animation code, you probably would not want to use `$(".item .item-inner")`, 'cause that's not specific neither.

Answer (score 1):

What i think about it that you must pass the `object` and its `index` in the animation loop function:

you can find a fiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/zDJJT/**

```
function animationLoop(it, index) {
            //---------^^--^^^^^----object and its index passed from click
    $(".ToBeAnimated").css({
        top: ($(".item ."+it).eq(index).offset().top - parseInt($(".ToBeAnimated").height()) / 2),
        left: ($(".item ."+it).eq(index).offset().left - parseInt($(".ToBeAnimated").width()) / 2)
    }).rotate(270);

    $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
        top: $(".item ."+it).eq(index).offset().top + $(".item ."+it).eq(index).height() - $(".ToBeAnimated").height() / 2
    }, 1000, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            rotate: "180deg"
        },1000, function() {
            $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
                left: $(".item ."+it).eq(index).offset().left + $(".item ."+it).eq(index).width() - $(".ToBeAnimated").width() / 2
            }, 1000, function() {
                $(this).animate({
                    rotate: "90deg"
                }, function() {
                    $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
                        top: $(".item ."+it).eq(index).offset().top - $(".ToBeAnimated").height() / 2
                    }, 1000, function() {
                        $(this).animate({
                            rotate: "0deg"
                        }, function() {
                            $(".ToBeAnimated").animate({
                                left: $(".ToBeAnimated").width() / 2
                            }, 1000, function() {
                                setTimeout(animationLoop, 1000);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });

            });
        });
    });
}

function clipIt() {
    $(".ToBeAnimated").css({"display":"block", "opacity":"0"}).animate({"opacity":1},800);
    animationLoop($(this).attr('class'), $(this).index());
    //------------^^passing curr obj^^---^^its index^^------passed in the function

}

$('.item-inner').click(clipIt);
```

What i have done here is that whichever you click `.ToBeAnimated` will animate to that bound, just passed the `class name` and its `index` to the `animationLoop(it, index);`

Comment: Thanks Jai That makes sense... I am getting VERY CLOSE.... I have been playing with variations of your code for a few hours but I just can't quite get it to work with my actual site... The difference is that your fiddle has ONE .item div with SEVERAL .item-inner links within it.... My actual site code has SEVERAL .item divs... EACH with their own .item-inner "CLIP IT!" link...

Answer (score 0):

If the scissors are loaded dynamically (ie. One pair of scissors for each coupon) you could append an integer to the end of the id. So you'd have a main container like 
div id="scissors_245"
where 245 is the coupon id. Then when you need to call any animation you always preface it with the id of the parent container.

```
$('#scissors_245 .leftside').animate(...
```

Then you don't have to rely on closest or the index of the element. If its moved or others are removed around it, you can still grab it all day long.

I'd also split a lot of this animation up into separate functions, so one function would be something like:

```
openShutScissors(id)
```

that opens and shuts the scissors and the other would be

```
moveScissors(id)
```

where id is the integer you appended onto the actual id. Then on your 'clip it' button you call

```
onClick="moveScissors(245)"
```

which triggers moveScissors() which then triggers openShutScissors()

This way you separate out all the craziness and just deal with one piece at a time.

Comment: You would also want to use the same integer in the coupon id so you can grab a path for the animation. like id='coupon_245'